# What is the meaning of skunk handler's clothing?

Tags: meaning-in-context, possessives, noun-phrases

> A terrible odor that was impossible to expunge permeated the **skunk handler's clothing**

Can you help me to understand this sentence? In specific, can you explain how I should interpret "skunk handler's"?

Additionally, how does "permeated" relate to this phrase?

Comment: What specifically is confusing you? All three of these words are easy to define... a skunk is an animal, a "handler" in this case is a person who cares for animals, and clothing is... clothing... certainly you can imagine that the wardrobe of a person who takes care of skunks would be very smelly?

Comment: Perhaps it's the noun **skunk** used as an adjective modifying **handler** which is in the possessive?

Comment: @TRomano That was the only thing that I could think of, too. Regardless, it would be good if the OP could clarify.

Comment: @Catija If the answer is obvious, I am sorry for my terrible English. I am confused of two things. the first has been mentioned by Tromano. the second is "**permeated** the skunk handler's clothing" is it some sort of reversing?

Comment: @Cardinal It's not a matter of being obvious... there's no need to apologize for your English. The point is that you need to be more specific when you ask questions so that we understand what confuses you. You didn't even ask about the "permeated" part itself.

Comment: @Catija You are totally right. I posted the question at 3:30 AM on local time. I was very tired.

Comment: OK, now it's just unclear what you're asking. :/ Reversing? Who what now?

Comment: @Catija I've edited agian

Comment: I've made an attempt to make your concerns more clear with my own edit. Please let me know if this reflects your question correctly. In this form, I believe the question may be worth reopening.

Comment: @Catija yeas it certainly does.

Answer (score 6):

What I imagine is confusing you is the following:

**skunk handler** : these two words together make up one person who is in charge of "handling" or "caring" for skunks. Likewise, a "snake handler" would be someone who is responsible for taking care of snakes.

Thus, the *clothing* belonging to the skunk handler (or **skunk handler's clothing**) is extremely smelly and impossible to clean.

Comment: Your answer could be improved if you explained why it means that. Simply rephrasing the sentence isn't always very helpful to learners trying to understand **why** something means something else.

Comment: @Catija Hope my edits make more sense!